# when image tag role be set button jsx-a11y show warning

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I need make image tag clickable, but I get a warning by jsx-a11y, how do I fixed it, I already read [no-noninteractive-element-interactions](https://github.com/evcohen/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y/blob/master/docs/rules/no-noninteractive-element-interactions.md), but I do not wanna wrap other div tag around img tag, because it will make a redundancy tag, so does any other way to fix this warning?

The warning is `[eslint] Non-interactive elements should not be assigned interactive roles.`

and my code is

```
  <img
    styleName="pic-id-code"
    src={picCodeImgSrc}
    alt="pic id code"
    onClick={this.refreshPicCodeImg}
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
    role="button"
    tabIndex="0"
  />
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use [`<input type="image" />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/image) for your use case, it is semantically correct and you won't need to add `role` or `tabindex` or any other `ARIA` tags to make it work and accessible.

There is a caveat as this doesn't actually return to normal state after click and remains focused so you need to call blur after your `onClick` logic. Here's the [simple demo](https://codepen.io/vikas-parashar/pen/mQmmbM) I made few days back to remove focus on click.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the best way to achieve this for a while now. This is hands-down the best and most correct solution!

Answer (score -1):

You can disable eslint for a specify line like this

```
// eslint-disable-next-line THE-RULE-HERE
<img
    styleName="pic-id-code"
    src={picCodeImgSrc}
    alt="pic id code"
    onClick={this.refreshPicCodeImg}
    onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
    role="button"
    tabIndex="0"
  />
```

Not sure what exactly your rule is but try this

```
// eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions
```

or

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-noninteractive-element-interactions
```

**Update after OP comment**

> ... but no work in react jsx

Try this

```
<img
        styleName="pic-id-code"
        src={picCodeImgSrc}
        alt="pic id code"
        // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions
        onClick={this.refreshPicCodeImg}
        // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions
        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
        // eslint-disable-next-line jsx-a11y/no-noninteractive-element-interactions
        role="button"
        tabIndex="0"
      />
```

`onClick` and `oneKeyPress` on img will also trigger warnings.

Comment: I tried the updated answer, but also got error, `Non-interactive elements should not be assigned interactive roles.`

Comment: Is that from the same line? Also need to check if the rule we are using is correct. Try the generic one without any rules `// eslint-disable-next-line`

Comment: yes, the same line, I use vscode and eslint plugin, so I can see red line highlight when get eslint error or warning

Comment: Which extension do you use for linting in vscode? Is it vscode-eslint? If yes try this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-eslint/pull/530

Comment: yes, I use this plugin, and I change vscode setting to `    "eslint.autoFixOnSave": true,`, so if eslint can fix it, it'll auto fix when I save the file, but not, and these `disable eslint` also does not work